# unexpected string constant error in R

Tags: r

I try to run tobit regression analysis in R. My tobit formula is below:

```
fm.tobit <- tobit(Eff "~"  SIZE + DEP + TERMDEP + CURRENTDEP + LOAN  + LIQUIDITY + HHI + ASSET GRW + NPL + CRAR + RWA + DKRIZ + DKAMU + DOZEL + DYABANCI + DISE, left = -inf, right = 1, data = veri)
```

but I receive this error

> : Error: unexpected string constant in "fm.tobit <- tobit(Eff "~""

I tried to delete the inverted commas "~" but It causes another error just like below:

> error: unexpected symbol in "fm.tobit <- tobit(Eff ~ SIZE + DEP +
>   TERMDEP + CURRENTDEP + LOAN  + LIQUIDITY + HHI + ASSET GRW"

could you help me to solve this situation.

Thanks..

Comment: Perhaps you need `paste` or `formula` i.e. `formula(Eff ~  SIZE + DEP + TERMDEP + CURRENTDEP + LOAN  + LIQUIDITY + HHI + ASSET + GRW + NPL + CRAR + RWA + DKRIZ + DKAMU + DOZEL + DYABANCI + DISE)`

Comment: Did you copy in the tilde from another source or did you type it yourself (ie, is the encoding the right one)?

Answer (score 1):

If the `tobit` is from `AER` package, we don't need to quote the tilde `~`.  Based on the `?tobit` help page

```
library(AER)
data("Affairs")
fm.tobit <- tobit(affairs ~ age + yearsmarried + religiousness + occupation + rating,
        data = Affairs)
coef(fm.tobit)
#  (Intercept)           age  yearsmarried religiousness    occupation        rating 
#    8.1741974    -0.1793326     0.5541418    -1.6862205     0.3260532    -2.2849727
```

The error is reproducible with

```
fm.tobit <- tobit(affairs "~" age + yearsmarried + religiousness + occupation + rating, 
              data = Affairs)
```

> Error: unexpected string constant in "fm.tobit <- tobit(affairs "~""

Based on the OP's second attempt, i.e. removal of quotes, as @ekstroem mentioned, it could happen when it is copied from another document